# ambiguous call in template error

Tags: c++

Can anyone tell me the cause of error ?

Error is

```
C:\web\template1.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
C:\web\template1.cpp|23|error: call of overloaded 'swap(int&, int&)' is ambiguous|
C:\web\template1.cpp|6|note: candidates are: void swap(X&, X&) [with X = int]|
c:\program files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1\include\c++\bits\move.h|76|note:                 void std::swap(_Tp&, _Tp&) [with _Tp = int]|
C:\web\template1.cpp|24|error: call of overloaded 'swap(double&, double&)' is ambiguous|
C:\web\template1.cpp|6|note: candidates are: void swap(X&, X&) [with X = double]|
c:\program files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1\include\c++\bits\move.h|76|note:                 void std::swap(_Tp&, _Tp&) [with _Tp = double]|
C:\web\template1.cpp|25|error: call of overloaded 'swap(char&, char&)' is ambiguous|
C:\web\template1.cpp|6|note: candidates are: void swap(X&, X&) [with X = char]|
c:\program files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1\include\c++\bits\move.h|76|note:                 void std::swap(_Tp&, _Tp&) [with _Tp = char]|
||=== Build finished: 3 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

---

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename X>
void swap(X &a, X &b)
{
    X temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

int main()
{
    int i=10, j=20;
    double x=10.1, y=23.3;
    char a='x', b='z';

    cout<<"i="<<i<<"\tj="<<j<<endl;
    cout<<"x="<<x<<"\ty="<<y<<endl;
    cout<<"a="<<a<<"\tb="<<b<<endl;

    swap(i,j);
    swap(x,y);
    swap(a,b);

    cout<<"i="<<i<<"\tj="<<j<<endl;
    cout<<"x="<<x<<"\ty="<<y<<endl;
    cout<<"a="<<a<<"\tb="<<b<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your `swap` conflicts with `std::swap`. Remove `using namespace std;` above and correct the rest code from `std` namespace.

```
std::cout<<"i="<<i<<"\tj="<<j<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"x="<<x<<"\ty="<<y<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"a="<<a<<"\tb="<<b<<std::endl;
```

Also it's worth reading [Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/72178)

Answer (score 3):

Rename `swap()` as `swap2()` or the like.  Or, better, never issue `using namespace std;`.

As written, your code introduces `std::swap()` through *iostream,* then dumps it atop your own `swap()` by `using namespace`.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a swap function declared somewhere in your code. Change the function's name or remove the declaration of the other swap function.

Answer (score 0):

This ambiguous errors occur due to using `std` functions as general functions.
There are two ways to overcome this.

1) Instead of declaring `using namespace std;` use `std::cout`
    whenever you need to print any and `std::endl` for new line.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename X>
void swap(X &a, X &b)
{
    X temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

int main()
{
    int i=10, j=20;
    double x=10.1, y=23.3;
    char a='x', b='z';

    std::cout<<"i="<<i<<"\tj="<<j<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"x="<<x<<"\ty="<<y<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"a="<<a<<"\tb="<<b<<std::endl;

    swap(i,j);
    swap(x,y);
    swap(a,b);

    std::cout<<"i="<<i<<"\tj="<<j<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"x="<<x<<"\ty="<<y<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"a="<<a<<"\tb="<<b<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

2) You can also change the `swap` to `Swap` to not conflict with the inbuilt `std::swap` function.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename X>
void Swap(X &a, X &b)
{
    X temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

int main()
{
    int i=10, j=20;
    double x=10.1, y=23.3;
    char a='x', b='z';

    cout<<"i="<<i<<"\tj="<<j<<endl;
    cout<<"x="<<x<<"\ty="<<y<<endl;
    cout<<"a="<<a<<"\tb="<<b<<endl;

    Swap(i,j);
    Swap(x,y);
    Swap(a,b);

    cout<<"i="<<i<<"\tj="<<j<<endl;
    cout<<"x="<<x<<"\ty="<<y<<endl;
    cout<<"a="<<a<<"\tb="<<b<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: All of this advice was already given more than seven years ago. What does your answer add? What is a "general function"?